# Sprite without animation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I'm trying to add a SpriteSheet that is shown in the layer but not animated yet, I want to animate onClick.

The problem is when adding the sprite to the layer, the sprite is not shown if its not animated on start.

In Cocos2D-iphone I have not this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look on the coocs2d-android master file :
cocos2d-master\cocos2d-android\src\org\cocos2d\tests\ActionTest.java

In this you can find the Animation class and compare your code with the test file...

or

write down your code ...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, show a static image (first sprite) until user clicks, then load the sprites and start animation.